# Set amount in Stripe Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, stripe-payments

I am working on Stripe payment in objectiveC. I have set cvc, account number etc in the CheckoutVC.m view controller.

```
- (STPCardParams *)getCardParams { 
    STPCardParams *cardParams = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];

    NSArray *dateCoponents = [txtExpirationDate.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    cardParams.number = txtCreditCardNo.text;
    cardParams.expMonth = [(NSString *)[dateCoponents firstObject] integerValue];
    cardParams.expYear = [(NSString *)[dateCoponents lastObject] integerValue];
    cardParams.cvc = txtCvv.text;
    return cardParams;
}
```

My issue that how can i set amount $10. 
Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass amount with your web service/api

Refer this link step by step,
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-stripe-payment-integration/

you will find postStripeToken() function, under which you can see amount parameter passed.

```
    let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
        **"amount": self.amountTextField.text.toInt()!,**
        "currency": "usd",
        "description": self.emailTextField.text]
```

Comment: Can you provide easy way. like cardParams.amount etc. It is very difficult.